# A system of modular equations

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, systems-of-equations

Is there a way to solve for $a,b,c,d$ in the following system?

$$
\begin{aligned}
\begin{cases}
ac & \equiv P \\
ad & \equiv Q \\
bc & \equiv R \\
bd & \equiv S
\end{cases} \pmod{M}
\end{aligned}
$$

Edit: You may assume $PS \equiv QR \pmod{M}$.

Comment: You certainly need $PS \equiv QR \mod M$ to find a solution.

Comment: @HansEngler: You may assume $PS \equiv QR \pmod{M}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that if there is a solution $a,b,c,d$ then it's not unique, as $at,bt,ct^{-1},dt^{-1}$ will also be a solution for any $t$ that's relatively prime to $M$.

Therefore you can fix any one of the variables, say $a$, and then solve $c\equiv Pa^{-1}$ and $d\equiv Qa^{-1}$ and then $b\equiv aRP^{-1} \equiv aSQ^{-1}$.

This is assuming that everything is relatively prime to $M$, but in practice we can divide out by any common factors ahead of time.